# How to immediately cancel a working BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a time taking process in `DoWork` of my `BackgroundWorker`.

Whenever I try to Cancel the job by `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()`, the `backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` becomes Pending and I should wait for the next iteration in my `DoWork`  to Cancel the job and stepping out of it myself.

Is there any way to Cancel the job immediately after calling it?

Comment: Check CancellationPending  more often?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  In general you can't safely terminate a thread "immediately", because it may be holding resources that would leak, and more importantly it may be holding locks.  You need to structure your worker to respect the cancellation flag and and safely exit as soon as possible.